# Remove resolution string from image url in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have following image url:

```
http://www.example.org/wp-content/blogs.dir/29/files/2013/02/Personalized-Results-Asterisk-600x417.png
```

Here url containing by default resolution i.e. `600x417.png` in it. I want to remove this resolution from this image url.

Final output of image url should be like this :

```
http://www.example.org/wp-content/blogs.dir/29/files/2013/02/Personalized-Results-Asterisk.png
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Edit the filename?  Not sure the purpose of what you are trying to do, so I don't know what direction to try and take an answer.

Comment: @Jon : I only want to remove that resolution string i.e. (600x417) from that image url so that it will take original image resolution instead of taking 600x417.

Comment: Ooh, ok, doing a `preg_replace` with the pattern `/\-*(\d+)x(\d+)/` for the answer below shall do the trick ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
$string = 'http://www.example.org/wp-content/blogs.dir/29/files/2013/02/Personalized-Results-Asterisk-600x417.png';
$pattern = '/\-*(\d+)x(\d+)\.(.*)$/';
$replacement = '.$3';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ : Yup it is.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ : Edited the code, now it wont check for all the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

Regex:`^(.*?)-\d+x\d+\.([^/]+)$`

Replace with:`$1$2`

Answer (score 0):

```
$str=preg_replace("/^(.+)-\d+?x\d+?(\.\w+)$/i","$1$2",$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace

```
$correct_url = preg_replace('`\-[0-9]*x[0-9]*(\.[^\.]*)$`','$1',$url);
```

There are a lot of ways.

Comment: you don't need to escape `.` if it's within `[]`